# Pasting into Excel VBA leads to an infinite loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to VBA and struggling with a simple script to copy-paste a formula.

What am I trying to achieve?

1. Lookup cells for all (non-empty) entries in column A
2. Copy a fixed range
3. Paste into column L and M

The problem I am facing:

The copy-paste works but doesn't stop at the last entry of column A. There seems to be an infinite loop.

Code:

```
For i = 2 To 250    
 
  If Ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
  Ws1.Range(Ws1.Cells(2, 12), Ws1.Cells(2, 13)).Copy
  Ws1.Cells(Row.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
  End If
Next i
```

I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: As a **Side note** you have to be very careful with conditions like `Ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""` to test if a cell is empty. E.g. if there's a formula in the cell resulting in an empty string `""` then this condition will regard the cell as empty. This might lead to bugs in your code. A good way to test for an empty cell is `IsEmpty(Ws1.Cells(i, 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, determine last row in column A:

```
lastRowInA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRowInA
    'loop body
Next i
```

Then, you want a copy fixed range, but you also pasting it in fixed range. You should paste it in N:M columns:

```
lastRowInA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRowInA
    Ws1.Range(Ws1.Cells(2, 12), Ws1.Cells(2, 13)).Copy
    Ws1.Range(Cells(i, 12), Cells(i, 13)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Next i
```